# Get array validation key in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation

Im using laravel 8.83.27

```
public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'price_per_image.array'      =>  'Price must be an array',
            'price_per_image.required'   =>  'Price per image  field is required',
            'price_per_image.*.required' =>  'Price per image '.preg_replace('/^[a-zA-Z_]*\./', '', ':key').' field required',
            'price_per_image.*.numeric'  =>  'You have invalid characters in the price field',
            'price_per_image.*.between'  =>  'Price per image '.preg_replace('/^[a-zA-Z_]*\./', '', ':key').' must be in between 0.1 to 1000',
];
}
```

it giving me result like this

```
Price per image price_per_image.0 must be in between 0.1 to 1000 Price per image price_per_image.1 must be in between 0.1 to 1000
```

but i want like this

```
Price per image.0 must be in between 0.1 to 1000 Price per image.1 must be in between 0.1 to 1000
```

Comment: Remove `preg_replace` and just add ths  `'price_per_image.*.between'  =>  'Price per image :attribute must be in between 0.1 to 1000',`

Comment: I have used it but its also returning :attribute as a string

Answer (score 0):

public function messages() { return [ 'price_per_image.array' => 'Price must be an array', 'price_per_image.required' => 'Price per image field is required', 'price_per_image..required' => 'Price per image '.preg_replace('/^[a-zA-Z_]./', '', ':key').' field required', 'price_per_image..numeric' => 'You have invalid characters in the price field', 'price_per_image..between' => 'Price per image '.preg_replace('/^[a-zA-Z_]*./', '', '').' must be in between 0.1 to 1000', ]; }